# Problems While Trying To Generate Random Numbers

Tags: javascript, web-applications, random

I'm trying to build a web application that generates a random number within a range(from/to) using this code:

```
function generateRandom(rFrom, rTo)
{
    var num;
    num = Math.floor(rFrom + (1 + rTo - rFrom) * Math.random());

    return num;
}

function btGenerate_onClick(event)
{
    var nFrom;
    var nTo;

    nFrom = document.getElementById("txtFrom").value;
    nTo = document.getElementById("txtTo").value;

    document.getElementById("lblResult").innerText = generateRandom(nFrom, nTo);
}
```

But while I was testing the web application using the properties `2` and `5` for `From` and `To` respectively, I got numbers like `22`, `210`, `20`, `27` and `211`. So how I can correct this so it will generate numbers that are between `2` and `5` as tried without sucess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have to explicitly turn the string values into numbers:

```
function generateRandom(rFrom, rTo)
{
    var num;
    rFrom = Number(rFrom); rTo = Number(rTo);
    num = Math.floor(rFrom + (1 + rTo - rFrom) * Math.random());

    return num;
}
```

<strike>The multiplication will do it implicitly for "rTo", but then</strike> you have to make "rFrom" a number for the addition, or else it'll be interpreted as string concatenation.

*edit* — oops I started with the wrong block of code.  This now has your original function, and all I changed was to explicitly convert the parameters to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
function generateRandom(rFrom, rTo)
{
    var num;
    num = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(rTo)) + parseInt(rFrom);

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Now I got numbers like `02`(which is acceptable), `22`, `23` and `42`(which aren't acceptable)

Comment: your problem is using string. You should parseInt(rFrom) and parseInt(rTo) to fix this.